# Erro: “Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction”

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em java que utilizo o Hibernate para fazer o mapeamento. Criei os DAO's das classes, mas ao fazer operações de insert, update e delete ele me retorna esse erro do MySQL.

Segue minhas classes (vou postar apenas o método de inserção para não ficar tão longo):

**MasterDAO.java** - Classe mãe de todos os outros daos, para ficar mais fácil a criação.

```
public class MasterDAO {

    public Session getSession(){
        return HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }

    public void inserirObjeto(Object obj){
        Session s = getSession();
        s.beginTransaction();
        s.save(obj);
        s.getTransaction().commit();
        s.close();
   }
}
```

**AlunoDAO.java** - Dao do aluno que extende o MasterDAO:

```
public class AlunoDAO extends MasterDAO{

    public void inserirAluno(Aluno aluno){
        inserirObjeto(aluno);
    }
}
```

**InsereDados.java** - Classe com método main para inserir objetos no banco

```
public class InsereDados {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
        aluno.setNome("João Neto");
        aluno.setCpf(777555);
        aluno.setDataNascimento(new Date(new String("09/05/1995")));
        aluno.setMatricula(2012030);
        aluno.setRg(123456);

        AlunoDAO alunoDAO = new AlunoDAO(); 
        alunoDAO.inserirAluno(aluno);
}
```

Ao executar isso gera o erro:

> Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

O mais engraçado é que as vezes funciona, tem vez que vai normal, já outras não. Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Isso tem cara de deadlock. Você pode demonstrar como é que `Aluno` se relaciona com outras entidades? Também vai a pergunta básica, se você enviar ao banco, de dentro da aplicação, um SQL simples feito na mão por fora do hibernate tal como `select * from aluno where 1=0`, ele funciona?

Comment: Será que não há algumas conexões fantasmas no banco de dados travando a tabela inteira? Já vi isso acontecer, e aí tem que derrubar essas conexões a força.

Comment: Victor, no momento não estou em casa, mas assim que chegar em casa eu posto o código do relacionamento, e quanto a executar um código simples, o mesmo também trava dentro do MySQL workbench, exceto select, que funciona tanto com o hibernate como sem.

Comment: Se trava dentro do MySQL Workbench, isso é um forte indício de que o problema não é o java e nem o hibernate, é alguma coisa no MySQL.

Comment: Executando o comando show processlist, o mesmo mostra alguns processos como sleep. Não sei se isso tem alguma coisa haver.

Comment: Mas sempre funcionou normal, serã que não pode ser alguma propriedade das tabelas que eu gerei com o hibernate?

Comment: :) Acho que você achou o problema. Provavelmente estes processos são conexões fantasmas. Se você puder matar eles, veja se o hibernate volta ao normal.

Comment: Justamente esses processos com sleep sao no banco que estou manipulando com o hibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o @Victor mencionou, podem haver transações "presas" (fantasmas) que travam a tabela toda.

Uma causa possível disso é um problema crítico do código: **falta tratar erros**.

No caso de uma falha qualquer no método `inserirObjeto` a transação pode não ser encerrada com *commit* ou *rollback* e a sessão do Hibernate pode nunca ser fechada.

Coloque um tratamento com `try/catch/finally`, onde o block `finally` deve sempre garantir o fechamento dos recursos abertos.

Exemplo:

```
public void inserirObjeto(Object obj){
    Session s = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        s = getSession();
        tx = s.beginTransaction();
        s.save(obj);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
    } finally {
        if (s != null) s.close();
    }
}
```

Se possível reinicie o servidor SQL para evitar problemas de bloquei atuais e teste novamente sua aplicação usando os princípios acima apresentados.

Comment: Assim que chegar em casa vou fazer um teste, vou dar um kill nos processos fantasmas e fazer a implementação do try. A noite dou um feedback, valeu!

Comment: Só uma dúvida @utluiz, eu importo essa Transaction do Javax ou do Hibernate? Porque importando do javax ele pede um try catch no rollback.

Comment: Deu certinho já, muito obrigado =)